# The meaning of would in this sentence

Tags: modal-verbs

Please tell me what "would" means in this sentence.

> In AmE, the phrase "go to hospital' **would** be not correct. One of the articles, *a* or *the*, **would** be necessary.

Answer (score -1):

"Would" is conditional - if you're using one language, "go to hospital" is correct, but if you're using it for another, it's not.

It means that in American English, "go to hospital" doesn't exist (just so you know, I'll tell you why).

A hospital is a place. "Go to the hospital" is an expression. "Go to a hospital" means any hospital you can find.

Exceptions like "go to school" are correct. 'School' is not commonly recognized as a place without "a" or "the" before it. It's recognized as a collective term for somewhere that you learn.

Comment: _Would_ is a conditional modal, and the preterit of _will_, in only a single language: English. Are you familiar with _modal_ verbs such as _will_? What does the phrase _"if you're using one language"_ mean in English?

Comment: That's not what I meant. I said that if you're using one language, **go to hospital** is correct.

Comment: The phrase _"if you're using one language"_ is without meaning. What is the "one language" to which you refer?